# Custom data store module for Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, dspace

I like Spring Data REST but I need to explore the possibility to use it without exposing directly our JPA Entities. Furthermore, our access layer is currently build using GenericDAO instead of repository (or Spring Data JPA).
So the idea is to build a custom spring data module that implementing the Repository interfaces allow me to benefit of all the other functionalities of Spring Data REST. The entities managed by our custom spring data module will be at the end DTOs of the original JPA entities.
I'm currently looking to spring-data-ldap as implementation to mimic as it looks as the most simple data module available but I'm facing with the following issue

1. we get an exception at the application startup saying

   ```
   Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.data.dspace.repository.support.DSpaceRepositoryFactoryBean required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.


   Action:

   Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your configuration.
   ```

   DSpaceRepositoryFactoryBean is our implementation that just return a very simple DSpaceFactoryBean that always return a banal implementation of the CrudRepository (all methods return null)

   ```
   @Override
   protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
           return SimpleDSpaceRepository.class;
   }
   ```
2. have sense this approach? or will be better to give up with Spring Data REST and just use Spring MVC + HATEOS?

Comment: you might be interested in https://github.com/jirutka/spring-data-jdbc-repository

Comment: You are asking two very different questions, and I'd consider one very opinion based.

Comment: Thanks for the link to spring-data-jdbc-repository I will take a look it seems very close to what I want to achieve. You are right the second question is in some way opinion based. I try to clarify a bit: I will like to have a list of features that Spring Data REST add on top of Spring MVC + HATEOS considering that I need to write my own spring data module

Comment: I have shared on github my current implementation https://github.com/abollini/spring-data-dspace